Задать стиль DataFrame в Pandas при записи в XLSX файл
Мне необходимо преобразовать данные в нескольких столбцах Pandas DataFrame перед записью их в XLSX файл.
with pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
  df.style.format('{:.2%}', subset=[13,14,15]) \
    .to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=False, index=False)

Данные записываются, но форматирование (перевод числа в процент) не применяется.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?


Датафреймы в pandas содержат только бинарные значения, без возможности их форматировать.

Есть разница между тем, что в датафрейме действительно находится, и тем, как это будет изображено для нас, людей.

То, что вы делаете командой df.style.format('{:.2%}', subset=[13,14,15]) возвращает объект типа Styler - сам датафрейм df не изменится.
(Объекты типа Styler возможно применить только для разных видов изображения того-же самого датафрейма в подходящей среде Питона, или для экспорта в HTML.)

Класс ExcelWriter умеет форматировать только ячейки, в которых Еxcel принимает столбцы типа datetime64.


Значит, ваш подход не будет работать.
Нужно

сначала экспортировать датафрейм в Excel - примерно так, как вы это делаете, но без попытки форматирования:
 with pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
     df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=False, index=False)


затем форматировать — или прямо в Excel-е (или его программной среде VBA), или например в Питоне применением того-же самого модуля openpyxl (атрибут .number_format для объектов типа Cell).


